# Adobe Illustrator: How can I draw lines from a shared origin to multiple points simultaneously?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a large number of ellipses in my project, and I wish to draw a (straight) line from each ellipse center to a single shared origin. Doing this manually would be very inefficient. Is there an automatic way to do this in one go?

Comment: The *only* possibility I can think of is scripting.

Comment: Illustrator is a direct modeler, so yes doing manually is what it is meant for.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we have to make it manually.

You made think the best way to achieve this.

So here we go:

- Select copy and lock the circles.
- Paste in front and convert the curves to straight lines using the Simplify Panel.
- Make all the circles(now squares) to 1% using the Transform Each Panel.
- Drag each point and align them.
  Remember each line is actually four anchor shape.

This is the best way I could think of.

The animated image below:

[image]

Comment: You can replace the individual dragging with scale tool!

Comment: I don't think so. Because those little anchors are actually squares. So we're dragging one of four anchors.

Comment: after the selection step obviously, just click on all of them once and scale to zero

Comment: After the selection. Now I got it.